# How can get button by tagName without id, class or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

I want to get button text without id, class or jQuery using tagName and write those text into p tag. My simple test code like below.
I hope you understand what I am trying to do.

```
            <button>Button 1</button>
            <button>Button 2</button>
            <p id="result" ></p>


            <script type="text/javascript">
                function tagName(tag){
                    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
                    var totalButton = buttons.length;

                    for(var i=0;i<totalButton;i++){
                        // here i want to check which button clicked?
                    }

                };

                    tagName("button").onclick = function(){
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = tagName("button").innerHTML;
                }
            </script>
```

Can you help me for completing this code?
*Note: I have only one function tagName()*

Comment: `here i want to check which button clicked?` what do you mean by that? what are you trying to build?

Comment: that's mean I trying to check which button clicked and get those button valo (text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function tagName(tag) {
            var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
            var totalButton = buttons.length;

            var r = []
            for (var i = 0; i < totalButton; i++) {
                // here i want to check which button clicked?
                r.push(buttons[i])
            }
            return r;
        };

        function onLoad() {
            tagName("button").forEach(function (item, idx) {
                item.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = item.innerHTML;
                });
            });
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="onLoad()">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <p id="result"></p>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Working fine. But I can't understand how it's working! Can you explain this with comment // ?

Comment: how about `function tagName(tag) { return Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName(tag)) }` or `return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName(tag))` for older browser?

Comment: awesome! you are so brilliant. You understand my problem just by one time. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
var obj = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

for (let item of obj) {
  item.onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = item.innerHTML;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But it's not what I am looking.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will do what you want.  It uses more modern Javascript, so it won't work on old versions of IE.

```
<button>Button 1</button>
<button>Button 2</button>
<p id="result" ></p>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function setButtonEvents(){
        let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");  // (returns a nodeList, like an array)

        for(let b of buttons){
            // here i want to check which button clicked?
            b.onclick=buttonClicked;
        }

    };

    function buttonClicked(e) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML;
    }
  setButtonEvents();
</script>
```

Comment: I can control/call any function from `setButtonEvents()` function.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but you can certainly add more code to the function.  If you want a button click to call multiple functions without chaining, you can use .addEventListener('click', functionName); once for each function you want to add.

Comment: I want to `return the button which just clicked`. Then I can write/get value like functionName().innerHTML or functionName().value etc

Comment: ah, just return e.target in the buttonClicked function then.

Comment: Though that won't work in context, as you won't be in another function when the click event is fired.  You can add code to the buttonClicked function.  e.target is the button that was clicked.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to change the `p` tag text depending on what button is clicked then you can achieve it like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onclick = function(e) {

    var isButton = e.target.tagName;

    if (isButton === "BUTTON") {
      var text = e.target.innerText
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = text;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you. But I want with function.